# Enable StateAndCountry Picklist using Metadata API in Sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx

I have tried deploying [AddressSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm?search_text=address) but that didn't enable it. I found out that for Scratch orgs there is a feautre [stateAndCountry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_stateandcountrypicklist) but couldn't find something similar for Sandboxes. Does this have to be a manual step for Sandboxes?

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Metadata API to edit existing states and countries in state and country picklists. You can’t use the Metadata API to create or delete new states or countries.

Need to configure state and country picklists in your sandbox org.

[State and Country Picklists Metadata API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_api.htm&type=5)

Below is the Package.xml file used to retrieve/deploy:

```
<types>
    <members>Address</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
<version>48.0</version>
```

Comment: While this is related material, I don't see how this answers the question as asked. Additionally, if you quote the documentation, please use the editor to mark the copied text as a quote.